# Solvability of System of Linear Inequations

Tags: inequality, algorithms, computational-complexity

I have a problem that I can formulate as a matrix inequality $c_{min}\leq Ax\leq c_{max}$:

- $c_{min}$ and $ c_{max}$ are **non-negative** column vectors of length $m$.
- $A$ is a matrix of dimensions $m\times n$ containing **positive** values
- $x$ is a **non-negative** column vector of length $n$.

For example ($n=m=3$):

$$\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{min} \\\beta_{min} \\\gamma_{min} \\\end{array}\right) \leq
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{r}
x_1 \\x_2 \\x_3\\\end{array}\right) \leq
\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{max} \\\beta_{max} \\\gamma_{max} \\\end{array}\right)
$$

I would like to find out an equation or inequality that allows me to check, whether there exists a vector $x$ that satisfies the inequalities, given a set of $c_{min}$ and $c_{max}$. So instead of running an algorithm to find a solution and thereby showing solvability, I would like to reformulate the problem so that I can check if there exists a solution in a simpler way. Ideally this should be possible to solve efficiently using a computer.

For $n=m=1$ the problem is trivial:

$$\alpha_{min}\leq a_1\cdot x_1 \leq \alpha_{max}$$

So the limits for the vector $x$ (in this case the scalar $x_1$) would be
$$ \frac{\alpha_{min}}{a_1}\leq x_1\leq\frac{\alpha_{max}}{a_1}$$
The resulting condition for solvability is therefore
$$\alpha_{min} \leq \alpha_{max}$$

For the case $n=1$, $m=2$ the inequality becomes
$$\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{min} \\\beta_{min} \\\end{array}\right) \leq
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
a_1 \\b_1 \\\end{array}\right)
x_1  \leq
\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{max} \\\beta_{max} \\\end{array}\right)
$$
so the condition for the existence of a solution is
$$ max\left(\frac{\alpha_{min}}{a_1}, \frac{\beta_{min}}{b_1}\right)\leq
min\left(\frac{\alpha_{max}}{a_1}, \frac{\beta_{max}}{b_1}\right)
$$

For $n=2$, $m=1$:

$$
\alpha_{min} \leq
\left( \begin{array}{rr}
a_1 & a_2\\\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{rr}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\\end{array}\right)
 \leq \alpha_{max}
$$
the condition again becomes
$$\alpha_{min}\leq\alpha_{max}$$

For $n=2$, $m=2$ I have
$$\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{min} \\\beta_{min} \\\end{array}\right) \leq
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
a_1 & a_2  \\b_1 & b_2 \\\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{r}
x_1 \\x_2 \\\end{array}\right) \leq
\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{max} \\\beta_{max}  \\\end{array}\right)
$$
and the inequalities become
$$\alpha_{min}\leq a_1x_1+a_2x_2\leq \alpha_{max}$$
$$\beta_{min}\leq b_1x_1+b_2x_2\leq \beta_{max}$$
The solution space here will be a plane bounded by four to six lines, namely
$$\alpha_{min}= a_1x_1+a_2x_2$$
$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2= \alpha_{max}$$
$$\beta_{min}= b_1x_1+b_2x_2$$
$$b_1x_1+b_2x_2= \beta_{max}$$
and potentially
$$x_1=0$$
$$x_2=0$$
Now I think the easiest solutions to check are where $x_1$ or $x_2$ are zero. So if
$$ max\left(\frac{\alpha_{min}}{a_i}, \frac{\beta_{min}}{b_i}\right)\leq
min\left(\frac{\alpha_{max}}{a_i}, \frac{\beta_{max}}{b_i}\right)
$$
is satisfied for i=1 or i=2, then there exists a solution. If that is not the case, then I would check the intersection points by solving
$$
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
a_1 & a_2  \\b_1 & b_2 \\\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{r}
x_1 \\x_2 \\\end{array}\right) =
\left( \begin{array}{r}
\alpha \\\beta  \\\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are all combinations of limits (in this case four).
So
$$\left( \begin{array}{r}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\\end{array}\right) =
\left( \begin{array}{r}
\frac{\alpha}{a_1}-\frac{a_1a_2\beta-b_1a_2\alpha}{a_1 \cdot det(A)} \\\frac{a_1\beta-b_1\alpha}{det(A)} \\\end{array}\right)
$$
This should be an inexpensive computation I think. For the special case where $det(A)=0$, the intersection with $x_i=0$ has to be calculated and the overlap checked.

Now if $m$ increases, then the same procedure as for the $2\times 2$-case has to be applied for all combinations of two inequalities and each solution candidate checked against all other inequalities until a solution is found. Since the number of times the procedure has to be performed grows with $m(m-1)/2$ this becomes computationally infeasible fairly quick.

Is there some other easier way to calculate the solvability of such a system? How could I utilize the problem structure to extend this to $n>2$?

Comment: I think the notion of polyhedral cone is relevant, check this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Polyhedral_and_finitely_generated_cones

Comment: You appear to have rediscovered [Fourier–Motzkin elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination). As you pointed out, it has really bad complexity: doubly exponential. There are some speedup methods discussed on that page, but it doesn't look like they change the fundamental complexity.

Comment: I know you said you wanted to reduce this problem to an (in)equation, but if I had to solve this sort of problem, I would just get a [linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) solver to solve it. If you have a constant objective function, then it will just tell you if the equations give a feasible region. LP solving is polynomial complexity.